# How do I create a custom search function using flask

Tags: python

Please kindly advice on how I can add a search function into the search box I have created using flask python.

Also I want to edit some information in my database using python flask and SQLAlchemy, with this code. Please help me make corrections.

```
def edit (id):
    users = User.query.get(id)
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        name = request.form['name']
        phone_number = request.form['phone_number']
        email = request.form['email']
        address = request.form['address']
        table = request.form['table']
        user_reg = User(name,phone_number,email,address,table)
        db.session.append(user_reg)
        db.session.commit()
        flash ('Edited')
        return  redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
    return render_template('edit.html', users=users)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that eventually worked

```
@app.route('/edit/<id>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def edit (id):
    users = User.query.get(id)
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        users.name = request.form['name']
        users.phone_number = request.form['phone_number']
        users.email = request.form['email']
        users.address = request.form['address']
        users.table = request.form['table']
        db.session.add(users)
        db.session.commit()
        flash ('Edited')
        return  redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
    return render_template('edit.html', users=users, id=id)
```